# Error compiling a c++ with Python bindings using mingw and msys

Tags: c++, python, mingw

My environment: Windows 7 64 pro, mingw32 (installed with 2012-04-26.exe installer), msys 1.0, Python 2.7.3 installed using the Win64 installer from python.org

I'm trying to compile a c++ program that has python bindings, using mingw and msys. When I run config from the msys shell, I get the errors

```
Could not link test program to Python. 
Maybe the main Python library has been installed in some non-standard library path. 
If so, pass it to configure, via the LDFLAGS environment variable. 
Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"

============================================================================
ERROR!
You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
============================================================================
```

I've tried to run configure with each of:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/c/Python27/libs"

./configure LDFLAGS="-L/c/Python27/Lib"

./configure LDFLAGS="-Lc:/Python27/libs"

./configure LDFLAGS="-Lc:/Python27/libs"
```

and all give me the same final error. I've posted the entire config.log file at http://pastebin.com/fZVjTeub. Any help?

Comment: Is your python path valid? it looks a little odd `c/Python27/Lib` should it not be `c:/Python27/Lib` or do you have a symbolic link pointing c to your c: drive?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, I tried the different variations and none seem to help. The msys shell has /c symlinked (is that the right term?) to c:/

Comment: See from the terminal where it thinks your python is located, and use that path, remember that it will be case sensitive so try to `cd` to different folders until you locate where the python folder is.

Comment: which python returns /c/Python27/./python.exe

Comment: where are the python libs located? could you try setting a symbolic link to the libs folder and passing this to ./configure?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Python27/Lib contains many .py files, Python27/libs contains many .lib files. I'm also not sure how to pass a symbolic link to configure.

Comment: the error is indicating it cannot find the python\lib folder, what I am saying is you could add a symbolic link to this folder and pass it, e.g. symbolic z points to python\lib folder then `./configure LDFLAGS=z or similar, beyond that I am not sure what else to suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was ultimately that I was using a 32-bit compiler and trying to link it to 64-bit Python.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've had to pass `LDFLAGS="-L/c/Python27/libs"` to `./configure`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Victor Why doesn't it provide an answer? This is how he solved the problem.

Comment: An answer shouldn't begin with *in my case*. You should provide a solution with some documentation to support it.